# how to create a wait function, which can be called multiple times in a code

Tags: javascript, selenium

I need to give demo of my code, and need to add a function for wait, so that that function can be called wherever script need to slow down. Please guide.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is Q&A forum, not give-me-code forum. Try to do it yourself and come back if you have a *specific* question on something in your code that doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I have written following reusable methods for `Explicit waits` and `Fluent waits`  in Selenium

```
/**
 * Purpose Fluent Wait for an element to appear on screen with a text
 * polling every 100ms
 * 
 * @param sec Time to wait for element
 * @param element WebElement to wait for
 */
public void fluentWaitforElementText(int sec, WebElement element) {
    new FluentWait<WebElement>(element).withTimeout(sec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .until(new Function<WebElement, Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebElement element) {
                    Boolean b = null;
                    if (element.getText().isEmpty())
                        b = false;
                    else if (!element.getText().isEmpty())
                        b = true;
                    return b;
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Purpose Wait for an element with text to appear on screen i.e. [Element
 * with expected condition with some text with length>0]
 * 
 * @param sec Time to wait for element
 * @param element WebElement to wait for
 */
public void waitForElementTextBooleanExpectedCondition(int sec,
        final WebElement element) {

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, sec))
            .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver dr) {
                    return element.getText().trim().length() > 0;
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Purpose Wait for an element until expected conditions are meet i.e.
 * [Element with expected condition that it is visible on screen]
 * 
 * @param sec Time to wait for element
 * @param Locator By object of webelement to wait
 */
public void waitForVisibilityOfElementLocated(int sec, By Locator,
        WebDriver driver) throws TimeoutException {
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, sec)).until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOfElementLocated(Locator));
}
```